# Identification of Richtech voltage regulator

Tags: voltage, identification, converter

I have this regulator to replace but cannot find anything with the marking.
Except it's similar to a RT8249C or B or A.
Marking is 2N=6C 708.
Is it the same as a 2N=2C?

[image]

Comment: what is the marking on the chip? ... the picture is grainy ... please edit the question ... do not add info in a comment

Comment: Edited thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

It's a Richtek RT8249C. 2N=6C is the same as 2N=2C, it was just manufactured in a different year. The markings are explained in the [datasheet](https://www.richtek.com/assets/product_file/RT8249A%3DRT8249B%3DRT8249C/DS8249ABC-02.pdf):

[image]

As you can see, the first number after the equal sign is the year code `Y` and the second number is the month code `M`.

Comment: Thanks for confirmation. I wanted to make sure and also was not sure about the letter a,b or c. But thanks a lot